# I keep getting this error while running my code

Tags: python, mmap

```
 File "/home/lums/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jplephem/daf.py",  line 118, in map_words
    m = mmap.mmap(fileno, length=j-i+skip, access=r, offset=i-skip)
ValueError: mmap length is greater than file size
```

I've been reading comments about an empty file but cannot find the correct answer.

Comment: Since this is an error from within the jplephem package: what is the full traceback? What is the (minimal) code you are trying to run?

Comment: What comments have you been reading, where?